# Docker: npm user permission Issue

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

Hi I am currently learning Docker and I am wondering why my code does return an error, although it is already resolved but I am just skeptical on why I am facing this issue.

Here's my problematic docker code:

```
FROM node:16.20.0-alpine3.17
RUN addgroup app && adduser -S -G app app
USER app
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY package*.json /usr/app
RUN npm install
COPY . .
ENV API_URL=http://api.myapp.com/
EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm run
```

Here's the issue that I encounter during the build phase:

```
#0 22.90 npm notice
#0 22.90 npm notice New major version of npm available! 8.19.4 -> 9.6.4
#0 22.90 npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.6.4>
#0 22.90 npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@9.6.4` to update!
#0 22.90 npm notice
#0 22.90 npm ERR! code EACCES
#0 22.90 npm ERR! syscall open
#0 22.90 npm ERR! path /usr/app/package-lock.json
#0 22.90 npm ERR! errno -13
#0 22.90 npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/usr/app/package-lock.json'
#0 22.90 npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/usr/app/package-lock.json'] {
#0 22.90 npm ERR!   errno: -13,
#0 22.90 npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
#0 22.90 npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
#0 22.90 npm ERR!   path: '/usr/app/package-lock.json'
#0 22.90 npm ERR! }
#0 22.90 npm ERR!
#0 22.90 npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
#0 22.90 npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
#0 22.90 npm ERR!
#0 22.90 npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
#0 22.90 npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
#0 22.90 npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
#0 22.90
#0 22.90 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#0 22.90 npm ERR!     /home/app/.npm/_logs/2023-04-07T10_17_38_968Z-debug-0.log
------
Dockerfile:6
--------------------
   4 |     WORKDIR /usr/app
   5 |     COPY package*.json /usr/app
   6 | >>> RUN npm install
   7 |     COPY . .
   8 |     ENV API_URL=http://api.myapp.com/
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm install" did not complete successfully: exit code: 243
```

BTW, just for everyones reference. Here's the fix that I got:

```
FROM node:14.16.0-alpine3.13
RUN addgroup app && adduser -S -G app app
USER app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
ENV API_URL=http://api.myapp.com/
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Thanks in advance for your answers folks!

I am expecting an explaination on why does my former Docker code is experiencing some issues

Answer (score 0):

Move the `USER app` line to the end of the file.

```bash
FROM node:16.20.0-alpine3.17
RUN addgroup app && adduser -S -G app app
...
RUN npm install
...
USER app     # <-- at the end, not the beginning
CMD npm run
```

`WORKDIR` and `COPY` normally create directories and files as root, even if the current user is something different.  In the sequence as you have it, you are the `app` user when you `RUN npm install`.  That wants to rewrite the `package-lock.json` file, but the previous line `COPY`ed it in owned by `root`, which is the permission error you see.

It shouldn't be harmful to run the image build as root.  When you're done, the `node_modules` tree and the rest of your application will be owned by `root`, but be world-readable, so running as `app` will still work fine.  This will give you a little bit of protection against accidentally overwriting your application's code, library, or static assets.

Comment: Muchas Gracias Amigo!

Good thing that you have pointed out the behavior of `WORKDIR` and `COPY` since it actually enlightened me on how they actually work under the hood.

Although I just have a question now on how my other code worked even though I put the `USER app` command in Line 3.